# why object file's debug_str so big?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

[image]

i use [objdump XXX.o -Ws] output many string lines, they are all struct names in my other c++ head files, but some of them are repeated, make my XXX.o so big.

can anyone tell me, are the repeated struct names in debug_str required for gcc ? and is there some parameters of gcc to reduce the repeated string?  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can anyone tell me, are the repeated struct names in debug_str required for gcc ?

Yes, they are required if you want to debug your program in a friendly way.

> and is there some parameters of gcc to reduce the repeated string? thanks.
>   Not directly, no.

You can remove the -g or similar arguments when you compile. Though that will not make source level debugging possible anymore.

You can also remove that information yourself, by running the `strip -g` command on your binary or object files.

Remember that this is debug information, used by a debugger. That information is not loaded or used when running your program normally.